Error while exporting data from BQ to GCP buckets
I wanted to have an automatic backup process for my BigQuery database. So I created scheduled queries which run the following SQL every day at 23:00 UTC (I work in CET timezone so 1AM my time, not sure if relevant):
DECLARE
  target_uri STRING;
SET
  target_uri = FORMAT( 'gs://bucket_name/dataset_name/table_name/%s/table_name_*.gzip', CAST(CURRENT_DATE() AS STRING));
EXPORT DATA
  OPTIONS ( uri = (target_uri),
    format = 'Parquet',
    compression = 'GZIP') AS (
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    `project.dataset.table`);

I run this for over 20 datasets and over 100 tables and most of them run without a problem. There are however around 2 per day which fail with the following error message:

BigQuery job scheduled_query_66ff804b-0000-2724-b8c3-30fd3812a524 (table ) failed with error INVALID_ARGUMENT: Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Permission denied while writing data. <MY_SERVICE_ACCOUNT> does not have storage.objects.delete access to the Google Cloud Storage object. Please make sure gs://bucket_name/dataset_name/table_name/2024-09-23/table_name_000000000645.gzip is accessible via appropriate IAM roles, e.g. Storage Object Viewer or Storage Object Creator. at [6:1]; JobID: 347408155156:scheduled_query_66ff804b-0000-2724-b8c3-30fd3812a524. Check BigQuery job details for more information.

What is weird is that the export actually goes through and all of the backed up files for that table seem fine.
I also feel it is important to mention that running the query 2x in one day (which should naturally never happen) results in a different error something to do with the overwrite = True parameter when running the query, which is specifically not added as I never want to replace what was already backed up. Additionally my bucket has retention policy so it is physically impossible to delete/overwrite anyway.
NB: In this post I replaced the specific dataset and table names. I use terraform to create all scheduled queries so they are automatically created for each table in each dataset.
I cannot really reproduce this error as the occurrence is seemingly random and re-running the query results in a different and expected error. It has never happened during manual testing, only since I deployed all the scheduled queries. I am hoping someone had a similar experience and managed to find a fix.
